# Dagger 2 singleton registry

Tags: kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2, micronaut

Hi in our project we use [micronaut](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/), and we have a code that looks like this:

```
beanContext.registerSingleton(foo::class.java, myFooObject)
```

Now we are trying to work with [dagger2](https://github.com/google/dagger), any idea how can I achieve something similar?

Answer (score 0):

In your dagger module you need to declare the provide method with the @Singletone annotation, for example:

```
@Module
class AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideMyFoo(): MyFoo {
        return MyFoo()
    }
}
```

Comment: but what if I want to add it from outside of the module? I mean what if I created it before the creation of this

Comment: You can return the your created object in this provide method then. But it doesn't look fine, to answer your question I need to understand details of your task.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do bind a singleton outside of the component.
by using  @BindsInstance

Here is an example of code where MyFoo is the class I want to inject outside of my comonent :

```
import dagger.BindsInstance
import dagger.Component
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Singleton
@Component(modules = [Car::class])
interface ComponentCar {

    fun getCar(): Car

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun setMyFoo(myFoo: MyFoo): Builder
        fun build(): ComponentCar
    }
}
```

Then later in the init code I do something like this:

```
val component = DaggerComponentCar.builder().setMyFoo(mySingleMyFoo).build()
```

Comment: Fine, congrats!
But it looks like you formulated your initial question a bit incorrectly.